# Updating instance of class after being pushed to a List

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-redux

Consider this dart code:

```
T t = T() // id field defaults to null
List<T> list = List()..add(t);
t.id = '123';
print('${list.first.id}') // What's output?
```

My question is about whether passed items to `List` are copied over to `List` or it's a reference.
I've encountered this ambiguity because I'm using `flutter_redux` where an action contains an instance of class `T`. on reducer, I add this `T` instance to my state. later on, in the middleware, I update this `t`'s id. But surprisingly `id` field on the state(in this case List) changes too! So my only guess is that objects are passed by reference. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Dart doesn't have copy constructors.  It's not possible for a List to create a deep copy even if it wanted to since it's not possible to do generically.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in Dart is an Object, so anything you are passing is passed by reference.

From the [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts):

> Everything you can place in a variable is an object, and every object
> is an instance of a class. Even numbers, functions, and `null` are
> objects. All objects inherit from the [`Object`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Object-class.html) class.

#### mutable/immutable objects

There is a difference however between mutable and immutable objects. Some objects are immutable, and therefore cannot be modified, while mutable objects can be modified.

An example of immutable objects is [`String`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings) objects.

An example of mutable object is [`List`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists) just like you observed in your example.

#### constness

Dart has another interesting type of object, and if you are familiar with `C++` or `C`, you would have encountered these. These are compile-time constants ([`const`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const)), and carry with them an attribute of immutability. Any object can be declared as const at the point of creation, provided the constructor being called has been declared as const.

**Watch out** with const objects if you are passing them to functions that expect mutable objects because attempting to mutate the constant, will result in a runtime error.

```
void modl(final List<int> l) {
  l.add(90);
  print(l);
}

void main() {
  List<int> l = const [1,2,3,4];
  modl(l); // Uncaught Error
  print (l);
}
```

Running the above program will result in an `Uncaught Error` because `l` is a compile-time constant.

See [Detecting when a const object is passed to a function that mutates it, in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63442051/detecting-when-a-const-object-is-passed-to-a-function-that-mutates-it-in-dart)