# Detecting when a const object is passed to a function that mutates it, in Dart

Tags: dart, constants

Take this example:

```
void modl(List<int> l) {
  l.add(90);
  print(l);
}

class Foo {
  final List<int> bar;
  const Foo(this.bar);

  @override
  String toString() => 'Foo{bar: $bar}';
}

void main() {
  var foo = const Foo([1,2,3,4]);
  modl(foo.bar);
  print (foo);
}
```

Running the above code results in a **runtime** `Uncaught Error`, but removing the `const` from

```
var foo = const Foo([1,2,3,4]);
```

allows it to work.

---

This seems like a bug to me because the const variable can be mutated and dart detects this at runtime, which means it has the means to detect when a const object is modified, but shouldn't this have been detected at compile time, seeing as const variables are called "**compile-time constants**".

If this is not a bug, is there anything in dart that allows us to detect at compile time when a `const` variable will possibly be mutated by an operation?

In C++, the compiler errors out when we try to do something like this. Is there anything we can do in Dart to avoid encountering this error at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

No. Dart `const` is a compile-time feature around object creation, but it's not reflected in the type system.
You can't tell from the type of any object whether it's a constant or not.

Usually that's not a problem because an instance of a class which *can be* const is unmodifiable. It's not guaranteed to be deeply immutable, but the instance itself cannot have its fields changed.

Lists, sets and maps can both be either constant and mutable. That's what you are seeing here.
The list argument to `const Foo(const [1, 2, 3, 4])` is constant, even if you remove the redundant `const` on the list literal. You would have the same issue with `new Foo(const [1, 2, 3, 4])`, which would also provide an immutable `foo.bar`, but which would otherwise be indistinguishable from `new Foo([1, 2, 3, 4])`. The only real difference is whether the list is modifiable or not, and the only way to detect that is to try to modify it.

Lists, sets and maps do not provide any way to detect whether they are mutable or not except trying, and catching the error.

When comparing to C++, Dart's notion of being `const` is a property of the object or, really, the way the object is created. That may have some consequences for the object. A `const Foo(..)` just creates a normal `Foo` object, but it can only create deeply immutable objects, and they are canonicalized. A `const [...]` or `const {...}` creates a different kind of list/map/set than the non-const literal, but that's not visible in the type.

In C++, being `const` is a property of an object reference, and it restricts how that reference can be used, but there are no constant objects as such. Any object can be passed as a `const` reference.

The two concepts are completely different in nature, and just happen to use the same name (and are also both different from JavaScript `const`).

Comment: Everything you've said makes sense and I understand this. Even in C++, const is also just a compile-time feature, and as the [dart docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const) say, _"Any variable can have a constant value"_, and this is the same in C++. My question is why the dart compiler isn't thoroughly enforcing the constness of a variable i.e. when the object is passed to a function which can modify it, and is there any way to hint to the compiler to do so.

Comment: @smac89 Unlike Dart, C++ has a notion of `const T*` and `const T&` types and `const` methods to declare that functions do not mutate objects.  Note that that's distinct from whether the object itself is actually constant.

Comment: What @jamesdlin says. I'll add it to the answer.